# MAT : Eclipse is not showing any running process

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mat, heap-dump

I have installed MAT tool in my eclipse. I have tomcat running on eclipse but no process is showing this, how to I proceed to fix get this working.

I have configured eclipse to use JDK ( in installed jre )
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have clicked on configure and given JDK path and it worked

Comment: What do you mean with give a JDK path. There is no such dialog