# Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT): Shows no currently running processes

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I'm trying to analyse a memory leak in one of my Java programs (which uses Swing), so I downloaded the Eclipse MAT.

What I've done so far:

1. Ran the program from within Eclipse by clicking the Run button.
2. Switched to the Memory Analysis perspective
3. Selected "Acquire Heap Dump from a locally running VM" while the program is running.

And what it shows is that there are no processes running. It basically looks like this:

[image]

Image from here: [MAT : Eclipse is not showing any running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522401/mat-eclipse-is-not-showing-any-running-process)

According to most answers on SO, you need to configure the HPROF jmap dump provider by setting its parameter to -jdkhome: [root file of your jdk installation].

I've done this. And yet I still cannot find any running processes. If it matters, I installed my JRE along with my JDK and not separately.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the heap dump that you are after, then you can use %JAVA_HOME%/bin/jvisualvm.exe (comes with JDK) to take a heap dump of your process. You can then analyze it with MAT, jvisualvm or any other tool.

Comment: I was actually wondering why MAT couldn't detect any running Java processes. But using the tool from this answer lead me to answering my question because of a "Local Applications Cannot Be Detected" warning when I started it up. So I'm grateful for that. I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so apparently this was a deeper, more underlying problem to do with folder permissions in Windows.

According to [this](https://visualvm.github.io/troubleshooting.html#jpswin), there are two reasons why Local Applications might not be detected:

> **Resolution:** This can happen on Windows systems, it's caused by misconfigured jvmstat technology used to detect the running
>   applications. There are two possible causes:
>
> 1. ***Insufficient permissions for %TMP%\hsperfdata_username* folder** - make
>      sure you're able to create a file in the directory and eventually
>      update the permissions for full folder access. Alternatively you can
>      just re-create the folder which should automatically set the correct
>      access rights. See see this [forums.sun.com thread](http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5133218&tstart=0) for more details.
> 2. *Having %TMP%\hsperfdata_username* folder on a FAT disk - by default jvmstat doesn't work on FAT disks due to security
>      restrictions. You can bypass the security check by setting the
>      -XX:+PerfBypassFileSystemCheck flag for both VisualVM and the monitored application. See the JDK bug #5042659 for more details.

This is because ([according to this thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20071017162737/forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5133218&tstart=0) archived from the above):

> Do you mind cd'*** to the directory that TMP is defined as and see if
>   there is a directory named hsperfdata_ where  is your
>   login. That is the directory where the instrumentation buffers are
>   mapped (as shared memory files). Each time a java process starts it
>   should create a file in that directory.

So what I understand from this is that Java was supposed to write a file to the `%TMP%\hsperfdata_<username>` folder. The file helped memory analysers detect Java processes. Lack of appropriate permissions meant that the file couldn't be written and the memory analysers couldn't detect the Java processes.

So the fix was to just give the appropriate permissions to this particular folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I find MAT turns error
`org.eclipse.mat.SnapshotException: Error getting Java processes list with 'jps'. Try to configure a JDK for the HPROF jmap provider` in path `MemoryAnalyzer-1.10.0.20200225-win32.win32.x86_64\mat\workspace\.metadata\.log`
Check jps: open win `cmd` and type `jps` return jps not exist.
Configure the path of `jps` to the environment.